# file:///usr/test/testDEmo/logback.xml,This URL indicating which drive

Tags: java, spring-boot

The above given URL is an entry of application.properties file where at startup time application loading all entry given in application.properties file.
at starting time application is not able to find the given path file:///usr/test/testDEmo/logback.xml,This URL indicating which drive?
is this URL belongs to LInux or window ?.and how to point this path to my local?

Comment: Welcome at StackOverflow. What are you trying to achieve? Configuring Logback for your Spring Boot app? Try to specify your exact needs!

Comment: @mle , No it is already configured ,and trying to understand the path given in Logback.xml.

Answer (score 0):

In the given url `file:///` means that the file is on your local machine, and the actual path of the file starts after that, i.e. `usr/test/testDEmo/logback.xml`.
The URL probably belongs to the Linux, you can type `file:///` in your browser to get a better understanding regarding the same.

Comment: Thanks ..It helped me out . It is local file only and used by the spring framework at runtime.

Comment: Glad to help! If the solution helped please upvote the answer and/or mark it as the correct answer. :)